# Need to mimic a router to test a SNMP monitor

Tags: monitoring, snmp, router

I just picked up a job where I'm to make some changes to a custom built SNMP monitoring daemon and test it.  The code changes to the daemon are quite simple, the trick is going to be testing it.

Are there any tools out there that will mimic an SNMP enabled router?  I'm only tracking traffic usage, so I'd suspect that I could write something that would do the job, but I'd prefer to use something real if possible.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate the Cisco router using http://www.ipflow.utc.fr/index.php/Cisco_7200_Simulator or Juniper router with Olive from JuniperClue.  But this is maybe too much overhead.

The other option is simulating the SNMP agent only, which is already answered in
[SNMP devices emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726876/snmp-devices-emulation).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a product called "mimic" from gambitcomm.com